# CSharpScript and dynamic objects

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a little scripting engine in my app that is able evaluate expressions just fine when the global context contains data from a database (using Dapper). e.g.

```
Date.Format(Data.CreatedAt, "h:mm tt")
```

However, if the data is passed as a dynamic object (from a json message on a queue) the evaluation fails with :

```
error CS0656: Missing compiler required member
```

The context looks like this:

```
public class ExpressionContext
{
  public dynamic Data { get; private set; }

  public ExpressionContext(dynamic data)
  {
    Data = data;
  }
}
```

If I change Data to be object rather than dynamic then I get this error:

```
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CreatedAt' 
and no accessible extension method 'CreatedAt' accepting a first argument 
of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)
```

which makes more sense to me.

So it seems like CSharpScript is not able to evaluate dynamic objects - and yet, a DapperRow works.

Im confused.